# Androidエミュレータで画面がどのActivityか確認したい。

Tags: android, android-studio

環境
AndroidStudio 1.2.2
OSX Ver10.10.4（14E46）
エミュレータもしくは実機(nexus5)

Androidエミュレータで現在開いている画面が、
ソースの中のどのActivityか確認したいです。
確認方法を教えてください。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ adb shell dumpsys activity activities
```

dumpsysを用いるのは如何でしょうか。
Stack先頭が最前面のActivity情報です。
"realActivity"にActivity名が示されます。